# What does the Ubuntu Firefox Modifications extension to firefox do?

Tags: firefox, ubufox

I'm presently running Firefox 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 9.04. My Firefox extensions include Ubuntu Firefox Modifications 0.9rc2. I've upgraded Firefox on this install a few times; as far as I can recall, some version of this extension was present when I initially installed Ubuntu 9.04. I have disabled it, mostly because I didn't know what it provided me, nor was I able to find out when I tried a bit.

What does the extension do?

Comment: This was also asked on superuser http://superuser.com/questions/65104/what-is-this-ubuntu-firefox-modifications-addon-in-ff-3-5-4-in-karmic

Comment: This extension also [disables multiprocess support](https://askubuntu.com/q/865525/298314). This issue appeared to be fixed at some point, but it seems we're back to having it mess with Firefox. Launchpad bug report can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubufox/+bug/1627808). If you type `about:support` into Firefox, you'll get *0/1 (Disabled by add-ons)* in the *Multiprocess Windows* entry.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The files here show some of the changes that Ubufox provides (custom branding, search preferences, etc.)

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/ubufox/trunk/view/head:/defaults/preferences/ubuntu-mods.js

Comment: It must be really difficult to provide a description, and links to additional resources, and other details, within the extension itself. Open Firefox > Go to Addons > Ubuntu Firefox Modifications > Click "more" > Your description: "Ubuntu Firefox Pack". Powerful stuff.

Comment: @GerardRoche haha felt the same. Whats the worst? It is still the same in 2016. It's over 9000 now.

Answer (score 43):

It came with [xul-ext-ubufox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xul-ext-ubufox) [image: Install xul-ext-ubufox]:

> Ubuntu-specific configuration defaults and apt support for Firefox.
>
> Adds Ubuntu-specific modifications to Firefox.
>
> Integrates the browser with Ubuntu to:
>
> - Enable searching for missing plugins from Ubuntu software catalog
> - Add the following options to the Help menu:
>
>   - Get help on-line
>   - Help translating Firefox
>   - Ubuntu Release Notes
> - Set homepage to Ubuntu Start Page
> - Display a restart notification after upgrading Firefox
> - Add ask.com to the search engines.
>
> You can uninstall this if you prefer to use a pristine Firefox install.

Homepage: https://launchpad.net/ubufox

Answer (score 11):

It enables Firefox addons to be installed through the package manager.

Comment: According to Synaptic, it also provides some Ubuntu-specific configuration defaults.