# Why do Firefox, Preferred Applications and x-www-browser disagree on default browser?

Tags: default-browser

Firefox claims it's the default browser (Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Check Now), Preferred Application also lists it as the default, but `x-www-browser` runs Chrome. Is there really more than one setting for the Ubuntu default browser?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/100693/18612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know where the Firefox / Preferred Application setting lives. However, x-www-browser is managed by the "alternatives" system in dpkg. You can interactively change it by typing this at a command prompt:

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

So, not a complete answer but might let you straighten things out and move on :)

**Update**
This page describes where Gnome keeps its preferred applications settings. The page refers to Linux Mint, but the same principles should apply: http://www.libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-linux-mint-ubuntu

So yes, they're different.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that worked for me. I have submitted a bug report to Firefox after reading your answer. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1218174