# Firefox multiprocess support disabled because of Ubuntu Modifications

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Recent versions of Firefox introduced multiprocess support. The entry `Multiprocess Windows` in `about:support` indicates the state of multiprocess support. In my case, it appears as `0/1 (Disabled by add-ons)`.

I disabled all my extensions and re-enabled them one by one to find the culprit(s). To my surprise, the extension causing the problem is `Ubuntu Modifications`. I disabled it, restarted Firefox, and the state of multiprocess support became `1/1 (Enabled by default)`.

The extension doesn't apear to do [anything major](https://askubuntu.com/q/226/298314).

1. Any idea when this will be [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubufox/+bug/1627290)?
2. Would disabling the extension break anything?

---

**Update**: The issue doesn't appear as fixed in Launchad, but in practice it is no longer causing problems and multiprocessing is now working with Ubuntu Modifications enabled.

**2017-05-13 update** - Currently no resolution for ubufox plugin, and no ETA.  Workaround is to disable/remove ubufox plugin.  Master tracking bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubufox/+bug/1627808.   If impacted, make sure to click on the "affects me" link at the top of it.

Comment: Just would like to add that if you install the extension "Add-On Compatibility Reporter", it shows which extensions have been marked *by their developers* to be multiprocess compatible - can save some time trying to identify. Also, on this old (but still valid) question about it, you get some very good info about what it does.